# Fit string inside specified rectangle

Tags: c++, winapi

I have string that needs to be drawn inside rectangle.

The problem lies in the fact that sometimes string can be too big to fit inside.

How can I adjust font size so the string can fit inside?

I have read the docs for `GDI` and found nothing. I still keep searching on the Internet, hoping to find something or to get an idea of my own...

`GDI`+ is an option too...

*The following code is posted in response to comment from user Jonathan Potter:*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>   
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>      // swprintf_s()
#include <math.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <string>
using namespace Gdiplus;

// enable Visual Styles
#pragma comment( linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
                         name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
                         processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
                         language='*'\"")

// link with Common Controls library
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus.lib")

//global variables
HINSTANCE hInst;

// main window procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
        RECT rcClient = { 0 };
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);

        int pageWidth = rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
            pageHeight = rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;

        HFONT font = NULL, oldFont = NULL;

        // target rectangle, text should fit inside
        Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, pageWidth / 4, pageHeight / 10);

        SIZE sz;

        GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, L"This is very long string that might not fit into specified rectangle",
            lstrlen(L"This is very long string that might not fit into specified rectangle"), &sz);

        if (sz.cx > (pageWidth / 4))
        {

            // get current font
            LOGFONT lf;
            GetObject(GetCurrentObject(hdc, OBJ_FONT), sizeof(lf), &lf);

            // scale it
            lf.lfHeight = MulDiv(lf.lfHeight, (pageWidth / 4), sz.cx);

            font = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

            oldFont = SelectFont(hdc, font);
        }

        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));

        // draw text in test rectangle 
        RECT rcText = { 0 };

        rcText.left = 0;
        rcText.top = 0;
        rcText.right = pageWidth / 4;
        rcText.bottom = pageHeight / 10;

        DrawTextEx(hdc,
            L"This is very long string that might not fit into specified rectangle",
            wcslen(L"This is very long string that might not fit into specified rectangle"),
            &rcText, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP, NULL);

        if (font != NULL)
        {
            SelectFont(hdc, oldFont);
            DeleteFont(font);
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
        return 0L;
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
        return 0L;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ::DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        return 0L;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
        return 0L;
    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// WinMain
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    // store hInstance in global variable for later use
    hInst = hInstance;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    // register main window class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Main_Window";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return 0;
    }

    // initialize common controls
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
    iccex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    iccex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex);

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    // create main window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Main_Window", L"Autofit text inside rectangle",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 50, 50, 200, 200, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Adjusting the font size isn't really a good idea. The Windows API drawing fiunctions support wrapping and as I recall, also "…" at the end of a too long string (but maybe I'm wrong about the latter, maybe that was only in Windows titles). If you don't want that shortening the usual solution is to provide either scrolling functionality (use a read-only possibly disabled edit control) or tooltip or both. But, if you really do want the text scaled to fit, then I suggest drawing it in a bitmap in a suitably large rectangle, perhaps at twice desired size, and scale that down.

Comment: Measure the string with the current font (e.g. with DrawRect(DT_CALCRECT)`), figure out the ratio by which you need to scale font size for the string to fit. E.g. if the string is currently twice as long, you need a font half the size.

Comment: *figure out the ratio by which you need to scale font size* It is not that simple. `DrawTextEx` with `DT_CALCRECT` extends the rectangle when string can not fit which makes my life harder...

Comment: `GetTextExtentPoint32` tells you how wide the string will be if that's what you want.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes it does, and I have used it in my own calculations. Still it failed to "save me". Perhaps I did something wrong, I don't exclude that option, so if you can elaborate I would appreciate it. I can also code example if needed.

Comment: I would recommend GDI+ it is very easy to use and is pretty powerful. Faster, can handle more image types, transparency etc... including fonts and font colors.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
int DrawText(_In_     HDC     hDC,
             _Inout_  LPCTSTR lpchText,
             _In_     int     nCount,
             _Inout_  LPRECT  lpRect,
             _In_     UINT    uFormat
            );
```

You specify the rectangle, and it ensures the text does not get drawn outside of that rectangle.  It also has a `DT_CALCRECT` flag if you need to calculate the rectangle based on the text and the current selected font.  Or you can use the `DT_END_ELLIPSIS`, `DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS` or `DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS` flag to truncate the drawing of the text with ellipsis added so the user can see when the text is longer than the rectangle.

Comment: Sadly, `DrawTextEx` extends original rectangle if text can not fit, read the docs about `DT_CALCRECT` flag carefully. It is exactly that behavior that disables me to use this API properly, I just don't know how to calculate scaling ratio that takes that behavior into account.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff, May I suggest, if the returned rectangle is larger than desired, you reduce the font size and try again. If a huge range of font sizes is possible, use a binary search to reduce the number of steps in the search. Also the search can be guided by the difference between the desired rect size and the returned rect size. E.g. if rect is 50% too big, reduce font size by 50% and search from there. It's possible that Uniscribe could have a higher-level solution, I haven't used it.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman: I have heard of Uniscribe but have never used it. I will give your other suggestion a try. Understand this is hard for me since this is my first try tackling this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, something like this should work, but I haven't tested it. Add appropriate error checking etc.

```
SIZE sz;
GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, pszMyString, lstrlen(pszMyString), &sz);

if (sz.cx > iMyMaximumWidth)
{
    // get current font
    LOGFONT lf;
    GetObject(GetCurrentObject(hDC, OBJ_FONT), sizeof(lf), &lf);

    // scale it
    lf.lfHeight = MulDiv(lf.lfHeight, iMyMaximumWidth, sz.cx);
    HFONT hNewFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

    .. use hNewFont to render string, remember to delete it when done
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code snippet but the result was not the one I expected. Text did not fit inside rectangle. Thank you for trying though. Is there anything else I can do to help you help me?

Comment: *Oh, this method would only work for text on a single-line* Tried it with single line, by using `DrawTextEx` with `DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP` but it failed. Text exceeds the right bound of the rectangle. After resizing the main window ( I am drawing in main window's `WM_PAINT` ) this effect persists. Text height exceeds lower bound, when resizing the  window down to *extremely small* size...

Comment: *So the font got smaller* No, the font remained roughly the same... *but it still overflowed?* Yes, horizontally. In extreme case where I downsize window to very small dimensions it also overflows vertically...

Comment: Did you select the new font into the DC before rendering the text? Please give more information rather than make me drag it out of you :) If the font doesn't get smaller then say that since that's the whole point of your question.

Comment: *Please give more information* Edited post with demo app.

Comment: It fails because you don't have an initial font to begin with, and the default System font isn't scaleable. Add `SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT));` after `BeginPaint`.

Comment: Font does get smaller, but still extends beyond rectangle horizontally. Also, when downsizing window to extreme, font can not fit vertically as well... Back to square one I guess...

Comment: There's a limit to how much you can scale fonts, and it's not an exact science. Run the resize code in a loop and keep shrinking it until it fits. Anyway, time for you to do some debugging/programming on your own rather than asking for hand-holding every step of the way.